# Restkit addConnectionForRelationship struggling

Tags: connection, restkit, relationship, restkit-0.20

I have two entities: `Contact` and `Listing`. A `User` can mark a specific `Listing` as its `Favourite`.
I set up the Relationships correctly and I'm able to add a `Listing` as a `Favourite` for the `User`.

The problem for me is the API side. It gives me only the `id`s of the relationship: `contact_id` and the `listing_id`.

How can I set up RestKit to map the relationships defined in the `Favourite`s object I get from the server which only gives me the two object `id`s of a contact and a listing?

Restkit Version: 0.20.3

JSON for Favorite:

```
{
         "contact_id": "1",
         "created_at": "2013-11-06T15:02:21.056Z",
         "id": "2",
         "listing_id": "3",
         "updated_at": "2013-11-06T15:02:21.056Z"
}
```

JSON for Contact:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "favorites": [
        {
             "contact_id": "1",
             "created_at": "2013-11-06T15:02:21.056Z",
             "id": "2",
             "listing_id": "3",
             "updated_at": "2013-11-06T15:02:21.056Z"
        }
    ],
    "first_name": Max, 
}


//////////
// Contact
//////////
RKEntityMapping *contactMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"PBContact" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
contactMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"object_id" ];
[contactMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"id": @"object_id" }];
[contactMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"given_name", @"address", @"birthday",
                                                 @"city", @"company_name", @"country",
                                                 @"email", @"family_name", @"gender",
                                                 @"mobile_number", @"note", @"phone_number",
                                                 @"state", @"zip_code", @"created_at", @"updated_at" ]];


//////////
// Listing
//////////
RKEntityMapping *listingMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"PBListing" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
listingMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"object_id" ];
[listingMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{ @"id": @"object_id", @"description": @"descriptions" }];
[listingMapping addAttributeMappingsFromArray:@[ @"address", @"name", @"bathrooms", @"bedrooms",
                                                 @"city", @"country", @"price", @"title",
                                                 @"zip_code", @"latitute", @"longitude", @"status",
                                                 @"total_area", @"year_built", @"property_type", @"listing_type",
                                                 @"size", @"lot_size", @"parking_spaces", @"view",
                                                 @"state", @"note", @"monthly_rent", @"created_at", @"updated_at" ]];


//////////
// Relationships
//////////

[contactMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"favorites" toKeyPath:@"favoriteListings" withMapping:listingMapping]];

[listingMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"favorites" toKeyPath:@"prospects" withMapping:contactMapping]];
```

Response Descriptor

```
RKResponseDescriptor *contactResponseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:contactMapping
                                                                                        method:RKRequestMethodAny
                                                                                   pathPattern:@"api/v1/contacts"
                                                                                       keyPath:nil
                                                                                   statusCodes:statusCodes];
```

Comment: What version of RestKit? Show the JSON that you receive and what mappings you are currently using for it.

Comment: Are the favourites always nested when you get the users? So you only have one response descriptor?

Comment: Yes the favourites are always nested. And I have one response descriptor descriptor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need (and should delete):

```
[listingMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"favorites" toKeyPath:@"prospects" withMapping:contactMapping]];
```

because the relationship is already being configured from the other side on the `contactMapping`. There shouldn't need to be any other changes by the look of it.

It isn't entirely clear why there are 3 ids:

```
"contact_id": "1",
"id": "2",
"listing_id": "3",
```

I'm assuming that `contact_id` always matches the outer contact that the favourites are nested in and isn't required. And that `id` is the useful piece of information (so your mapping is correct).

In your Core Data model, `favoriteListings` and `prospects` should be the inverse of each other.

---

Based on your latest comments, I think you need to create a new and different listing mapping. This mapping only contains `@"listing_id" : @"object_id"`. This will either link to an existing listing entity or create a placeholder that can be filled in later. This is the mapping that you should use as the relationship on `contactMapping`.

Comment: The id is the id of the Favorite object coming from the server. (I dont't have this object in CoreData) And the contact_id and listing_id tells me that contact 1 set listing 3 as its favourite. So Restkit should add the listing with id 3 to the favouriteListings of the Contact.

Comment: Listing details comes from another request? Do you have the listing objects and you need to connect them (foreign key mapping)?

Comment: I get my contacts details via /contacs the listings details via /listings
I'll get the favourite relationship (contact_id & listing_id) either via the nested favourite within a contact or via /favourites

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you Wain!